# How can you ask for user input when also using a text file in unix shell in c++?

Tags: c++, file, shell, unix, mips

I run my code using `a.out < file.txt` and I read all of the file when I try to use `cin >> variable` to ask the user for input it does nothing.

Comment: Use command line arguments? `a.out file.txt` or `a.out do-this < file.txt` will both work. Or put the command into the file itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you invoke your program with `a.out < file.txt`, you're asking the shell to pipe the `file.txt` content in as the standard input for `a.out` *instead* of letting the keyboard provide standard input.  If that doesn't suit you, then add a command line argument to specify the filename, use an `ifstream` to open it and read from that instead of `cin`, the use `cin` for the keyboard input.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    const char* filename = argv[1];
    if (std::ifstream in(filename))
    {
        // process the file content, e.g.
        std::string line;
        while (getline(in, line))
            std::cout << "read '" << line << "'\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "unable to open \"" << filename << "\"\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    // can still read from std::cin down here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need additional user input after your stdin, you have to open your controlling terminal which is convinently named "/dev/tty". Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ifstream tin("/dev/tty");
  ofstream tout("/dev/tty");

  tin.tie(&tout);

  while (true) {
    string input;

    tout << "> ";
    getline(tin, input);

    if (input == "quit")
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

To convince yourself that above will not read redirected file, a simple test:

```
$ echo "quit" | ./a.out
>
```